# Launch Excel from MVC with actual file, not download copy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, httpresponse

I need to be able to launch Excel and open and eiut a specific file from an MVC application.

The application is for internal use only and users will have access to the folder containing the excel file.

I have looked at the File method below

```
var dir = location + "Filename.xlsx";
var cd = new ContentDisposition
{
    FileName = "Excel Spreadsheet",
    Inline = true
};
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
return File(dir, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

However, this opens Excel with a copy of the file downloaded to the users's download directory.  So if they make any changes, these do not update to the original.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? If so, how?

Many thanks,

Chris.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible. You're trying to use server-side code (C#) to initiate a client-side action (open Excel with a particular file). That's never going to work.

Comment: In Classic ASP: `response.redirect "file://corp.mycompany.com/DEPTS/MY_DEPT/Stuff/Test.xlsx"`  works fine for me.

Comment: @CraigW. Yes its possible (just like clicking on a `mailto:` link opens the users email app). It involves (1) creating a custom Http protocol (e.g.`excel://somefile...`, (2) a separate console app that launches the executable using `Process.Start()` and (3) a separate installer package that installs the app and modifies the registry on the client.